# Regex for shopping input line

Tags: php, regex

I have input lines like this:

```
1 soccer ball at 10
2 Iphones 4s at 199.99
4 box of candy at 50
```

And I want to get the first digit, the item itself and the price (I don't want the "at").

I have done the following regex:

```
/^(\d+)\sat\s(\d+\.?\d*)$/
```

But as you can see I am missing what comes before the "at". What should I put there?

Comment: Where does this format come from? It's not impossible to parse, but have you considered XML/JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you.

`/(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+at\s+([\d\.,]+)/`

Comment: I like this one beast as it supports multiple spaces and .+? between 'quantity' and 'at price'. Plus it's ready to support thousand formatted number with a , in them even.. if it's not very strict :) Added my strict(er) version too...

Comment: Ok that it matches multiple spaces (just add a +) but this would match  this: `1 soccer ball at .3.23.42.3.,,,,`

Comment: omg ^^
here's a better one: `/(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+at\s+(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)/`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version:

```
// double escaped \ as it's supposed to be in PHP
'~(\\d+)\\s+(.+?)\\s+at\\s+(\\d+(?:,\\d+)?(?:\\.\\d+)?)~'
// catches thousands too but stays strict about the order of , and .
```

*Cheers!*

**PS: Might fail for products that codes over 1 million of bucks** :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(\d+)\s(.+?)\sat\s(\d+\.?\d*)$/
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/fE7aV8)

Here you have `(\d+)\s([\w ]+)\sat\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

As you can see in the demo, the explanation

```
/(\d+)\s([\w ]+)\sat\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g
1st Capturing group (\d+) 
    \d infinite to 1 times. Digit [0-9] 
\s Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
2nd Capturing group ([\w ]+) 
    Char class [\w ] infinite to 1 times. matches one of the following chars: \w 
        \w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d] 
\s Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
at Literal `at`
\s Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
3rd Capturing group (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) 
    \d infinite to 1 times. Digit [0-9] 
    Group (?:\.\d+) 1 to 0 times. 
        \. Literal `.`
        \d infinite to 1 times. Digit [0-9]
```

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)